# How to save the parameters value between functions call?

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I'm trying to create a weather app, sending Ajax requests to OpenWeatherMap. I've got an error in w.getWeatherFunc, when I'm giving the function sendRequest the parameter of w.weather and then giving the same parameter to the function displayFunc, which I'm calling next.

Here is what I've got in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weather' of undefined
    at displayFunc (weather.js:46)
    at weather.js:78

How can I fix this and make it work?

```
function Weather () {
    var w = this;

    var weatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?'; 
    var appid = '&appid=c0a7816b2acba9dbfb70977a1e537369';
    var googleUrl =  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
    var googleKey = '&key=AIzaSyBHBjF5lDpw2tSXVJ6A1ra-RKT90ek5bvQ';

    w.demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    w.place = document.getElementById('place');
    w.description = document.getElementById('description');
    w.temp = document.getElementById('temp');
    w.humidity = document.getElementById('humidity');
    w.getWeather = document.getElementById('getWeather');
    w.addCityBtn = document.getElementById('addCity');
    w.rmCityBtn = document.getElementById('rmCity');
    w.icon = document.getElementById('icon');
    w.wind = document.getElementById('wind');
    w.time = document.getElementById('time');
    w.lat = null;
    w.lon = null;
    w.cityArray = [];
    w.weather = null;

    function sendRequest (url, data) {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
            } else {
                console.log(request.status + ': ' + request.statusText);
            }
        }

    }

    function displayFunc (obj) {

        console.log('obj ' + obj);
        w.icon.src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + obj.weather[0].icon + '.png';

        var timeNow = new Date();
        var hours = timeNow.getHours();
        var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + timeNow.getMinutes() : timeNow.getMinutes();
        w.time.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes;

        w.place.innerHTML = 'Place: ' +  obj.name;
        w.description.innerHTML = "Weather: " + obj.weather[0].description;
        w.temp.innerHTML = "Temperature: " + w.convertToCels(obj.main.temp) + "°C";
        w.humidity.innerHTML = "Humidity: " + obj.main.humidity + '%';
        w.wind.innerHTML = 'Wind: ' + obj.wind.speed + ' meter/sec';
    }


    w.convertToCels = function(temp) {
        var tempC = Math.round(temp - 273.15);
        return tempC;
    }


    w.getWeatherFunc = function() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location){
                w.lat = location.coords.latitude;
                w.lon = location.coords.longitude;

                var url = weatherUrl + 'lat=' + w.lat + '&lon=' + w.lon + appid;

                var result = sendRequest(url, w.weather);
                console.log(result);    
                displayFunc(result);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Browser could not find your current location');
        }
    }


    w.addCityBtn.onclick = function() {
        var newCity = prompt('Please insert city', 'Kiev');

        var gUrl = googleUrl + newCity + googleKey;
        var newCityWeather = null;
        sendRequest(url, newCityWeather);

        var location = newCityWeather.results[0].geometry.location;
        var newUrl = weatherUrl + 'lat=' + location.lat + '&lon=' + location.lng + appid;

        sendRequest(newUrl, w.weather);

            displayFunc(newCity);
            w.cityArray.push(newCity);
        }

    window.onload = w.getWeatherFunc;

    setInterval(function() {
        w.getWeatherFunc();
    }, 900000);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax **return** returns into the browsers engine. As its async you need to create a callback:

```
function sendRequest(url,data,callback){

 //if the data was received
 callback(data);
 }
```

Use like this

```
sendRequest("yoururl",data,function(data){
displayFunc(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you pass the obj to the function it will save it one scope higher. after that, if you don;t pass the object the one you saved earlier will be used.

```
var objBkp;
function displayFunc (obj) {
    if(undefined === obj) obj = objBkp;
    else objBkp = obj;
    // rest of code here
}
```

Comment: I wasnt trying to solve any errors i was answering the question you asked. Perhpas you should consider restating the question.

Comment: I believe that's what I am doing here: I have a global variable w.weather, which I pass to functions and which is supposed to change it's value, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

In your `sendRequest` you are passing only the value of w.weather, not its reference. JavaScript doesn't pass variables by value or by reference, but by [sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). So if you want to give the value to your variable you should do this inside your function `sendRequest`:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        w.weather = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    } else  {
        console.log(request.status + ': ' + request.statusText);
    }
}
```

Also, if you are using the attributes, you don't have to pass them in the function as arguments. Besides that fact, it would be good if you also create `get()` and `set()`

Comment: Youre generaly right, but the link has nothing todo with your answer. Null is a primitive type and therefore passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `console.log(result);` in `getWeatherFunc` gives you?
The problem as I see it is that in the `displayFunc` the parameter passed is undefined.

Comment: I know you cant comment yet, but this is rather a comment. Please delete it